# DNS help, server not responding outside home network

Tags: dns, ip

I am aware that this question does not really pertain to programming but I have now resorted to using you guys, so please help!

So I believe my problem resides in the DNS region, I am hosting a web server on my raspberry pi and am trying to use it to host my website(codetendency.com), I bought my domain from godaddy.com and I pointed "@" to my raspberry pi's IP address and when I try to access my website at home through my home network it works out, but when I tried to access it from my phone on my mobile data, the server doesn't respond.

I would greatly appreciate any help you guys could give me.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate ports open on your firewall (router) such as port 80 for http and 443 for https?

Try to do this on our "modem" which acts as a firewall in this case.

Comment: By router, in this case, your modem probably is taking care of the ports

Comment: I added a port forwarding connection on my router if that is what you are getting at.

Comment: What's the IP address of the Raspberry PI? Try connecting to it to determine if it's really a DNS issue or something else. It's 192.168.0.201?

Comment: i can connect to it fine through its IP while on my home wifi, but if i try to go to it through any other internet connection it doesnt work, and yes that is the ip

Comment: Then I think you can rule out DNS at least. I can't connect with IP address or the domain so it's not a DNS issue. If it was just a DNS issue, you'd be able to connect from outside the network with IP *and* domain name.

Comment: ahh, forgive my noobness then.
Do you perhaps know what is happening or missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right ports forwarded?

Comment: And does your ISP block port 80? Maybe try to use a diff than ordinary port? Also, i assume a static Ip address setup for the device? And did you restart modem? Some models have to be restarted to have port forwards take effect.

Comment: I forwarded port 80, i dont think my ISP blocks port 80.
and a static IP on my modem or PI?

Comment: it is tcp not udp for type of traffic?

Comment: I think i figured it out. You are using a private not a public ip address for your web server. 192.168.0.201 is a private IP address.

For it to work as a public website you need it associated with a public IP address not one that's internal to your network.

addendum: it looks like someone already said that in the answers something I didn't see...

Comment: The only reason I found this out is I tried to do a reverse lookup on the IP using https://mxtoolbox.com/. So you can verify that an IP address is public using that tool.

At command line, `dig -x` does a reverse lookup.

Answer (score 1):

The name `codetendency.com` resolves to the IP address `192.168.0.201`. That address is part of the private address space (see [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html)), which is not routed on the public Internet. If you want your server to be visible on the public Internet, you must provide a real IP address.